# upgrade exchange 2010 to 2013 (just OWA)

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

I am interesting in deploying Exchange 2013 OWA components / - CAS only role.   Historically in upgrades the backend Mail Role was the last role one would upgrade and one would install CAS/HT first.   I have seen some docs that say the only real requirement is being on Exch2010SP3.  I am currently on Exchange 2010

So the question is , can I light up a new CAS role to take advantage of the new OWA?  My goal is to leave the rest of my infrastructure alone, but take advantage of the mobile web capabilities.

Thanks,
Rich

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is forward compatibility with Exchange 2007 SP3 RU 10/2010 SP3 to support Exchange 2013 environments but there is currently nothing in Exchange 2013 to support backward compatibility to previous versions of Exchange, include 2010.  Although, co-existant support will be on the way with Exchange 2013 CU1, which is slated for release very soon (Q1).

It is also worth mentioning that an Exchange 2013 environment will look slightly different as support for the Hub Transport role has been wrapped into the Mailbox role.  The CAS is still defined as a separate role but will incorporate a few additional responsibilities that it did not have in Exchange 2010.

Essentially without both 2010 SP3 and 2013 CU1, co-existence will not be complete.

http://www.expta.com/2013/02/exchange-2010-sp3-and-exchange-2013.html